# Fusion Tables styling

Tags: maps, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to apply multiple styles to a Google Fusion Table Layer.

This does not colors all polygons that are in an array to the different color:

```
styles: [{
where: 'Cadmio = 3391',
polygonOptions: {
fillColor: '#e60000',
fillOpacity: 1
}
}, 
{
where: 'Cadmio = 1074',
polygonOptions: {
fillColor: '#ffaa00',
fillOpacity: 1
}
},
{
where: 'Cadmio = 370',
polygonOptions: {
fillColor: '#38a800',
fillOpacity: 1
}
},{
where: 'Cadmio = 156',
polygonOptions: {
fillColor: '#74c200',
fillOpacity: 1
}
},{
where: 'Cadmio = 90',
polygonOptions: {
fillColor: '#98e600',
fillOpacity: 1
}
},{
where: 'Cadmio = 71',
polygonOptions: {
fillColor: '#ffff00',
fillOpacity: 1
}
}]
});
```

The last one Whereclause is not working, It seems that de javascript code just accept 5 Whereclauses? What can I do? also I stylised it with Fusion tables map-view and I would like to set the opacity of the polygons with Javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fusion Table and Google Maps API: Only first classes are used for rendering features](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20814235/fusion-table-and-google-maps-api-only-first-classes-are-used-for-rendering-feat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limit of 5 styles per map.  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#fusion_table_styles

`Styles can only be applied to a single Fusion Tables layer per map. You may apply up to five styles to that layer.`

You can, however set styling using the [Fusion Tables API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/articles/fusiontables_styling) and expand on that limitation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fusion Table 'IN' clause to get it colored. I am able to color whole Australia state with this. Please let me know if you have any more query.